# Ansible jinja2 filter reject

Tags: ansible

I need to reject "*" from stdout lines.

```
"stdout_lines": [
    "rchinnn01",
    "rchinnn02",
    "*"
]

- set_fact:
  nfs_clients:  "{{ nfs_clients_out.stdout_lines | reject('search','*') | list }}"
```

Playbook output:

```
TASK [set_fact] *****************************************************************************************************
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: error: nothing to repeat
fatal: [rchinnn03]: FAILED! => {"msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

Answer (score 5):

Regex '[*]' works. The play below

```yaml
vars:
  my_lines:
    - "rchinnn01"
    - "rchinnn02"
    - "*"
tasks:
  - debug:
      msg: "{{ my_lines|reject('match', '[*]')|list }}"
```

gives (abridged):

```yaml
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        "rchinnn01", 
        "rchinnn02"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using equalto instead of search:

```
- set_fact:
  nfs_clients:  "{{ nfs_clients_out.stdout_lines | reject('equalto','*') | list }}"
```

like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24041885/conditionally-join-a-list-of-strings-in-jinja

Answer (score 0):

Please use as below:

```
- set_fact:
     nfs_clients: "{{ nfs_clients_out.stdout_lines | reject('match','rchinnn*') | list }}"
```

[Please check jinja2 version details](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.10/templates/#reject)

Comment: I used provided syntax, but it's taking only "*" from stdout_lines. But my requirement is vice-versa, I need everything to be assigned to a variable except "*" . I tried by replacing rchinnn* with "*", but it's taking * as wildcard and it's rejecting everything.